# IE - "This page contains both secure and non-secure items"

Tags: internet-explorer, https, security

I've googled and googled for an answer to this and have found loads of answers - all saying pretty much the same thing.  Remove any absolute references to images, scripts etc.  I did that, but it's made no difference.

I searched the code for the string "http://" and made them relative (I've then changed some of the outbound links back to http to prevent searchbots finding a duplicate (https) version of our entire site) - but I don't think that's a problem, is it?

Please, could anyone take a look at the code, and see if they can find anything?  The page is here:
https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/bikehireform.php

Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your rotating image gallery.  If that's removed, the error goes away.  Move the "startGallery" script block after the "myGallery" div, then change this line...

```
window.onDomReady(startGallery);
```

to just

```
startGallery();
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks.  That seems to get rid of the non-secure malarkey, but now the JS isn't working and I wouldn't have a clue how to sort that.  The error I'm getting is Webpage error details

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 87
Char: 3
Code: 0
"URI: https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/scripts/jd.gallery.js"

Comment: Doh - sorry, I'm going too quickly.  I didn't read your full solution.  I've now moved the script block as you said, it gets further, but still doesn't load the images:

Webpage error details

Message: 'this.galleryData.0.image' is null or not an object
Line: 266
Char: 4
Code: 0
"URI: https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/scripts/jd.gallery.js"

Comment: I had a similar issue using the cloud-zoom jquery plugin on IE7. I don't understand why, but moving it out of jQuery(document).ready solved the problem.

Comment: How did you narrow down the issue causing that problem? I would love to know that, because I'm stuck on the same kind of problem. Don't know if you will reply, i'm commenting on a 1 year old thread.

Comment: To narrow down the problem, I would just start removing code until the problem goes away.

Answer (score 5):

These are all the resources called when you load that page.

- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/bikehireform.php
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/style.css
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/css/jd.gallery.css
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/scripts/mootools.js
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/scripts/jd.gallery.js
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/scripts/rollover.js
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/CalendarControl.css
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/CalendarControl.js
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/favicon.ico
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/phone.gif
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/email-icon.gif
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/wheel-icon.gif
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/foot-icon.gif
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/logo.jpg
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/beaconssmall_crop.jpg
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/feetsmall_crop.jpg
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/girlsonbikes_cropped.jpg
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/llangorse_crop.jpg
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/smallview_crop.jpg
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/tintern_crop.jpg
- https://smarticon.geotrust.com/si.js
- **http**://evssl-ocsp.geotrust.com/
- **http**://evsecure-ocsp.geotrust.com/
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/images/favicon.ico
- https://smarticon.geotrust.com/smarticon?ref=www.droverholidays.co.uk
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/css/img/loading-bar-black.gif
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/adultform.php?number=0
- https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/childform.php?number=0

So on line 328 change...

```
<!-- GeoTrust QuickSSL [tm] Smart  Icon tag. Do not edit. -->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"  TYPE="text/javascript"  
SRC="//smarticon.geotrust.com/si.js"></SCRIPT>
<!-- end  GeoTrust Smart Icon tag -->
```

to...

```
<!-- GeoTrust QuickSSL [tm] Smart  Icon tag. Do not edit. -->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"  TYPE="text/javascript"  
SRC="https://smarticon.geotrust.com/si.js"></SCRIPT>
<!-- end  GeoTrust Smart Icon tag -->
```

Comment: BTW - I used Tamper Data(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) for FireFox to generate that list.  It's an invaluable tool for debugging and hacking the web.

Comment: Thanks - I don't think this is it though (would be ironic, wouldn't it, if it were the Geotrust Seal causing these messages!).  Both Fiddler and HttpFox say it's pulling those links through https:// - isn't that what the src="//" is intended to do? (Never seen it before, just guessing).

Answer (score 1):

On any page accessed with SSL, check that any Ajax requests are using SSL, or IE will complain. Also, if you have a Google Analytics on your page, change it from `http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js` to `https://ssl.google-analytics.com/urchin.js`.

Comment: There isn't any GA code, but the "new" GA code (been around for over a year) handles HTTPS fine. So if you're using urchin.js, I'd recommend upgrading to ga.js.

Answer (score 1):

There is a geotrust.com link on the page, is that https?
I also see a lot of `http` links to your `.co.uk` site itself.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I think the geotrust link is https://.  The links to our .co.uk site should be absolute, if I understand it right, so that they don't lead searchbots off into a duplicate, https version, of our entire site - but that shouldn't cause any errors, should it?

Comment: @Luke, I did a quick scan with something like `CptSkippy`. Felt the `geotrust.com` link was a problem.. guess its not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked all the scripts and stylesheets you're using for external references? Maybe there's a background image referenced with http:// ?

I noticed a couple of things in the code. First, the geotrust.com script - does // at the start use the current protocol? I've never seen that before. Second, some AJAX - again, make sure this is calling https.

Try removing an element or two at a time and see if the problem goes away. Another thing you can do in scripts, is check for https ("paraphrased" from Google Analytics code):

```
var jsHost = ( (document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://" );
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + jsHost + "YOURSITE.COM' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```