# Javascript : is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

I was having a problem with IE finding both secure and non-secure items on a page.  This seems to have been sorted thanks to a solution by David (many thanks!) who suggested altering the JS we use to display a gallery of images at the top of the page.

The issue now is that the gallery doesn't work!

Here's the error message:

Webpage error details

Message: 'this.galleryData.0.image' is null or not an object
Line: 266
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/scripts/jd.gallery.js

The page is:
https://www.droverholidays.co.uk/bikehireform.php

I don't understand JS very well so it would be great if anyone can tell me what I need to do to make this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bikehireform.php` change the line that says

```
startGallery();
```

to

```
window.addEvent('domready', startGallery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - would you  mind having another look please as I made that change and am now getting all 6 images displayed in the window!

Comment: OK - that's sorted.  (I'd missed moving a bit of the script).

I'm now getting the IE warning again though - so it's something to do with the 'domready' command though - what is that doing?

Answer (score 0):

In looking at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234990), I personally think CptSkippy's answer is still the correct one.

Stick with the onDomReady approach and make sure your external assets are being loaded from http***s***

Comment: Thanks for your input - to be sure, I tried reversing David's suggested change to the JS and implementing CptSkippy's suggestion.  I still get the IE message (which I don't when the JS is changed).  For the sake of "belt & braces" though, I've left the explicit reference to https which CptSkippy suggested in the Geotrust link.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... I think I may have got it.  I substituted 'load' for 'domready' in Rob's solution, above, and now I don't get the IE warning, and the script works.  It seems to be a bit slower than before, would that make sense?