# IE secure and unsecure items issue

Tags: security, internet-explorer, https

I'm trying to get rid of the error pop-up window that appears in IE saying "page contains both secure and non-secure items". I have made sure all the links are pointing to https:// rather than http://. I have also looked at the fiddler and firebug logs to see that all the requests are being made to https:// links only.

Here's a similar question asked on SO : [IE - "This page contains both secure and non-secure items"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234990/ie-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-non-secure-items)

The guy whose answer was accepted hit right on target. I wish I knew how he debugged to narrow down to that solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To solve this problem we need more information, such as a link to the page or some sample code.  The other question pretty much covers the usual ground for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to actually load a resource in order to trigger the warning, a reference is all it takes. The `<object>` used to load a Flash applet is enough (if you reference the HTTP URI for the Flash Plugin).

The easiest thing to do is to open up the source and search for 'http:' with your editor. If that doesn't turn up anything, do the same with the output of `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[[0].innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do a top-down or bottom-up approach to try to track down the issue.  Top-down is where you'd start commenting out stuff until it goes away while in the bottom-up case you strip out everything and then slowly start adding back in things like Flash, Javascript, and CSS as it may be some include or function that is the culprit.